# Track when users click a button that originated from Twitter

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I know how to set up an event in Google Analytics to track if a button has been clicked.

My question is how do I track a specific audience segment, so if the user originally came from a Tweet, landed on a page and then clicked a download button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have options...

**Option 1:**

Set up your button tracking via GTM. You'll have to specify what's being clicked in GTM (.pdf, .mp3, etc.)

Then in GA, view your button clicks through Events (Reports > Behavior > Events). Add a Secondary Dimension for **Source/Medium** and you'll see who came via Twitter.

---

**Option 2:**

When you post something to Twitter, use [UTM params](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/). Then, you can track the incoming leads from Twitter via campaigns (Reports > Acquisition > Campaigns). Look for Twitter under your Campaign Source.